# Hibernate : how to get records from composite key using Criteria Query

Tags: java, hibernate

I have added the composite filed in hbm files as follows

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="EmployeeSignin" table="EMPLOYEE_SIGNIN">
<composite-id name="id" class="EmployeeSigninId">
        <key-property name="empId" type="string">
            <column name="EMP_ID" length="10" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="signinDate" type="date">
            <column name="SIGNIN_DATE" length="7" />
        </key-property>
</composite-id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now I want to Query as follows

```
select * from EmployeeSignin where emp_id='12345' and signin_date > 'some initial date' and signin_date<= 'some last date'
```

I am not getting how can i achieve the same because there is composite key which refers to EmployeeSignId. how can i create criteria query in this case ?

I tried below but getting 0 records

```
Criteria empAttendanceCr=session2.createCriteria(EmployeeSigninId.class);
Criterion attdDateCondition = Restrictions.conjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("empId", user.getEmpId()))
                .add(Restrictions.le("signinDate", lastDate))
                .add(Restrictions.ge("signinDate", startDate));

        List empAttendanceList=empAttendanceCr
                .add(attdDateCondition).list();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue solved.

I tried below which worked

```
Criteria empAttendanceCr=session2.createCriteria(EmployeeSignin.class);
        //EmployeeSigninId empId=new EmployeeSigninId(user.getEmpId().toString());

        Criterion attdDateCondition = Restrictions.conjunction()                    
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id.empId",user.getEmpId().toString()))
                .add(Restrictions.le("id.signinDate", lastDate))
                .add(Restrictions.ge("id.signinDate", startDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Criteria query also provides to add Criterion on primaryId directly 
Something like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria("the class you want to fetch");
criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq("The primary id"));
```

Now this primary Id in case of Composite Key is a java object, so can we use this directly ?
Yes we can if we properly define the equals() and hashCode() functions in our composite key object and the code would look like:

```
Criterion attdDateCondition = Restrictions.conjunction()                    
          .add(Restrictions.idEq("id", new CompositeKey("empId", "lastDate", "startDate"));
```

Assuming that CompositeKey is your java object for composite key, and it has a constructor which accepts three arguments like shown above.
I have not done this using xml mapping and hence don't know exactly know how to define equals and hashCode functions in XML.

### Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Hibernate jpa 2.1 and above use

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeSignin> query = builder.createQuery(EmployeeSignin.class);
Root<EmployeeSignin> root = query.from(EmployeeSignin.class);
query.select(root).where(
    builder.equal(root.get("id").get("empId"), user.getEmpId().toString()),
    builder.le(root.get("id").get("signinDate"), lastDate),
    builder.ge(root.get("id").get("signinDate"), startDate),
);
Query<EmployeeSignin> q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
List<EmployeeSignin> employeeSigninList = q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score -2):

I have implemented the below solution to solve this issue.

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<ProductMapping> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ProductMapping.class);
Root<ProductMapping> root = criteriaQuery.from(ProductMapping.class);
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(
criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("ck_productmapping").get("supplierCode"), supplierCode),
criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get("ck_productmapping").get("productCode"), productCode));
Query sqlResult = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<ProductMapping> productList = (List<ProductMapping>)sqlResult.getResultList();
```