# Where clause on composite key in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-key

I think I'm missing something pretty big but to me hibernate seems VERY limited.

I have the following table (simplified slightly):

```
USER_ID | USER | TARGET_ID | TARGET_USER |  EFFECT_DATE | REQUEST_NO | EXPIRY_DATE |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a11     | jon  |   a22     |    steve    |  21/12/2014  |   555324   |  28/12/2014 |
a11     | jon  |   a33     |    jim      |  23/12/2014  |   555324   |  28/12/2014 |
a11     | jon  |   a44     |    bob      |  24/12/2014  |   555324   |  28/12/2014 |
a22     | steve|   a33     |    jim      |  24/12/2014  |   555324   |  28/12/2014 |
```

The huge issue is that there are 3 composite keys on:

USER_ID, TARGET_ID and EFFECT_DATE

I realise this isn't easy to work with but it's what I have been given so I don't have much control about the design of the table.

I have connected to my DB using hibernate using the following composite key mapping:

```
<composite-id name="actAsID">
        <key-property name="userID" column="PROXY_USER_ID" type = "string" />
        <key-property name="targetID" column="TARGET_USER_ID" type="string"/>
        <key-property name="effectDate" column="EFFCT_DATE" type="date" />
</composite-id>
```

This works absolutely fine and I can add users remove them and search for them. The issue comes when searching for a user it seems I HAVE to provide values for User ID, Target ID and Effective date i.e. only pulling one row of data each time. This leads me to believe I can only get one row or I can get all of them which seems very limited.

I have four main use cases here:

1) Getting all rows in table 
2) Searching a USER_ID to give me all the rows with that USER_ID 
3) Searching a TARGET_ID to give me all the rows with that TARGET_ID 
4) Searching based on a given USER_ID AND TARGET_ID

I did have in the mapping file just the ID set to USER_ID but then this only allows me to get all the users or all the rows with that USER_ID i.e. I can't use a where clause on TARGET_ID.

Comment: Composite keys are discouraged in Hibernate, partly for this very reason. Consider revising your DB schema - for example, you appear to have multiple users with the same user_id. Once the table has been re-architected, you should have a PK that you can reference in Hibernate.

Comment: I've already said that I fully realise this but have no control over the DB schema and even if I had a PK to use I still would surely get the same issue? 


I want to be able to search for:
WHERE(USER_ID = "a11")
or
WHERE(TARGET_ID="a22")
or
WHERE(USER_ID ="a11" AND  TARGET_ID = "a22")

My question therefore is how do I generate where clauses that are not on an ID field within hibernate?

I did effectively create my own ORM using a JDBC and am now struggling to see the benefit of hibernate.

Comment: As far as I know you can simply query for `actAsID.userID = 'foo'` or `actAsID.targetID = 'bar'` etc?

Comment: Ah, if you're just wanting the WHERE clause as per your comment, are those columns mapped within the Hibernate XML (outside of the composite-id construct)? If so, you should have no problem with WHERE clauses. EDIT: Post your XML if it helps.

Comment: No problem if you just use where condition in the HQL to search `from Table t where t.userId = ?` should work for you

Comment: @Dave they are indeed sorry should have mentioned that too.

I guess I just need to run a HQL to search in that case then. I think my confusion was with the following: if I'm running HQL how does this benefit me from just writing plain old SQL with a JDBC which I now see is that abstraction that Hibernate provides i.e. it's much easier to swtich to another DB I just need to use another dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can either use HQL or Criteria within Hibernate.

For example the following code gives me all users with a USER_ID of A11:

```
List<ProxyUser> Users = session.createCriteria(User.class)
             .add(Restrictions.eq("actAsID.userID", "11"))
             .list();
```

Some good examples of HQL:

http://www.journaldev.com/2954/hibernate-query-language-hql-example-tutorial

Using criteria with composite keys:

[Hibernate : how to get records from composite key using Criteria Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633941/hibernate-how-to-get-records-from-composite-key-using-criteria-query)